# Designing abstract type and related abstract functions in Julia

Tags: python, julia

I want to implement a type from where I would like to build other subtypes.

The supertype would be something similar to this.

```
abstract type A end
function process end

@keywdef mutable struct B<:A
    a
    b
end

function B(items::AbstractArray)
    a = items
    b = Dict()
     
    for (i,x) in enumerate(items)
        b[x] = i
    end

    B(a,b)
end

function process(object::B)
    object.b
end
```

What I want to achieve is a sort of blueprint in a supertype which can later be customized for any subtype.

The idea here is that I want a type A which would define a set of functions (optional and required).  Later I can create subtypes of A implementing methods to the functions of A.

For example the I can define an optional empty function `process` for types A and then later for B (subtype of A) I can implement the method.

I am still learning the ropes in julia so I wanted to know if the example that I have given is the correct way of doing what I have explained.

Specifically I want to do something similar in Julia like the sample Python code below:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, items: list):
        self.items = items

    def process(self):
        b = Dict()
        for (i,x) in enumerate(items):
            b[x] = i
        return b
```

Then I any other class can inherit the class B.

```py
class C(B):
   #further operations
```

Comment: Thank you @phipsgabler for the edits. I was typing on my phone and have made some mistakes.

Comment: This is a duplicate from https://discourse.julialang.org/t/designing-abstract-type-and-related-abstract-functions/45300/6 and your coide is not a valid Julia code.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel yes I had posted this earlier in the julia discourse forum and had got the answer over there. However I forgot to mark it as a duplicate here .

Comment: I think this is a better subject for discourse and answered you there as well.

Comment: That's right will mark the link here to that post as I am not sure if I can delete this post.